# chromedriver not raising exception on failed get request

Tags: python, selenium

I initialize chromedriver like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
```

Then I try to connect to nonexisting website like "http://examplee3k2op.com/" for example.

```
driver.get("http://examplee3k2op.com/")
```

I expect to get an exception, but nothing happens. How to fix it?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  try this out. You should also be adding a service driver for the newer versions.

Comment: The website will throw an error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED as well.

Comment: Obvious that you will receive error on webpage that site is not reachable since it is not exist. but no exception will be there in the console for sure assuming your chrome driver is in same location as your python script.